# Salvar latitude e a longitude no swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps, geolocalização

Eu tenho esse código no meu ViewController para capturar a localização atual dos usuários:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userMapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = manager.location!.coordinate
    print(location.latitude)
    let latitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let longitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta)
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span)
    self.userMapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
}
```

Eu tenho outro arquivo swift com as funções do banco de dados, e eu preciso salvar a latitude e a longitude para armazenar no banco.

Como eu posso armazenar a latitude e a longitude em um variável fora da função locationManager?

Me disseram que eu teria que transformar isso: `let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate` em uma variável de instancia.

Alguém sabe me disser como eu resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Victor,

Existem algumas maneiras diferenciadas de resolver o teu problema. Não é um problema de Swift em si, mas sim de *design*. Não é fácil pensar da "melhor maneira" logo de primeira, a experiência vem com o tempo. Vamos lá!

Primeiro ponto: tenta desacoplar o teu código o máximo que der. O `UIViewController` não deve saber como a localização é adquirida. Ele só deve ter uma maneira de obtê-la, com o mínimo de conhecimento possível, seja por injeção de dependência ou por meio de serviços. Além disso, se você "terceiriza" a obtenção da localização, o serviço pode ser reutilizado pelo sistema inteiro, e não só por esse `UIViewController` em específico.

Segundo ponto: não utilize variáveis globais. Existe uma série de razões para embasar essa afirmação, que estão fora do escopo dessa pergunta.

Vamos tentar criar um serviço para obtenção de localização, por pura didática. Talvez a questão da localização não seja tão importante para o teu app e isso seja bem *overkill*, mas isso é um forum público e talvez essa resposta ajude outros usuários, alem de disseminar boas práticas para a comunidade.

Criei aqui para você um [serviço de obtenção de localizações](https://gist.github.com/lvbarbosa/6432e8225b59e56e987298b3f77cdd38), escrito em Swift 3. Se você quiser, pode copiar pro teu projeto. Se você fizer isso, a obtenção da localização fica totalmente desacoplada e no `UIViewController` (ou em qualquer lugar que você queira obter a localização do usuário), a chamada se reduz a isso:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func qualMinhaLocalizacao() {
        GPSLocationService.shared.obterCoordenada(permitirAnterior: false, callback: self.receber)
    }

    private func receber(coordenada: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        NSLog("\(coordenada)")
    }
}
```

Não precisa passar nada por *segue*, não precisa de variável global, é *thread-safe* e, modéstia parte, elegante. Por favor, se alguém achar problemas, me fala que eu arrumo.

Acredito que pela maneira como o Swift é escrito, é possível entender o que acontece ali. Porém, caso haja alguma dúvida, por favor pergunte que eu terei o maior prazer em te ajudar.

Obs.: No iOS 9, existe uma maneira bem mais simples de obter localizações únicas, sem ficar ligando e desligando o GPS. [Documentação](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestLocation).

Links para leitura, caso queira estudar um pouco sobre os tópicos abordados!

- [What is Decoupling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244476/what-is-decoupling-and-what-development-areas-can-it-apply-to)
- [Why is Global State so Evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)
- [Injeção de Dependência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia)
- [*Thread Safety*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Vou ler esses links sim!